# How can I encode this in ScalaCSS?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to translate some CSS to ScalaCSS and I can't quite figure out how to encode a pattern of "class subclass".  Here is a specific example:

```
.navbar-top-links {
   margin-right: 0;
}

.navbar-top-links li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-top-links li:last-child {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [quickstart](https://japgolly.github.io/scalacss/book/quickstart/standalone.html) you can see the use of `&` to define child styles:

```
".navbar-top-links" - (
    marginRight(0),

    &("li") - (
        display.inlineBlock,

        &.lastChild -
            marginRight(15 px)
    )
)
```

Comment: Ok, yes, I missed the pattern of '&("x")'.  That looks like what I need.  Now I need to figure out how to render that out so I can debug it!  Thanks

Comment: Same page, just below: To see the generated CSS: `println( MyStyles.render )`

Comment: That doesn't work as expected.  The example is used against a stand-alone stylesheet.  When I tried it on an inline stylesheet, all I got was the object reference dumped out.  And when I tried to add the .render or .renderA method, it gave me a compile error of "could not find implicit value for parameter r: scalacss.Renderer[Out]"

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. The very next page in the quickstart is about inline sheets and it too says to use `printLn( MyStyles.render )`.

Comment: Agreed.  Instead of rendered CSS, I get the following: template.pages.DashboardPage$Style$@1  (where Style is my inner, inline style object).  Does it work for you?

Comment: Finally figured it out:  Style.render[HTMLStyleElement].outerHTML